# Solve the system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Solve the system: The last column is the vector b
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 4 & -5 \\
        4 & 3 & -5 & 8 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

I reduced it down to

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & -17 & 23 \\
        0 & 1 & 21 & -28 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Now I have to express it in terms of:

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        x1 \\
        x2 \\
        x3 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

x3 is free and I believe the answer to be something along the lines of

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0\\
        0 & 1\\
        ? & ?\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Not sure what the ? values are.

Comment: A few things.. Firstly, I don't know how you row reduced, but you didn't get what I got (your last column is wrong). Secondly, is your last column your vector $b$? If so, $x_1$ and $x_2$ aren't "free", $x_3$ is..

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! Fixed that and added that the last column is the vector b.

Comment: Check your row reduction again too.

Comment: Ok I did that and see I put a negative in the wrong spot. I think it's fixed now. I'm still confused on how to express the ?s as a number.

Comment: Thank you!

So if I want to express this in terms of x1, x2, x3. Would it be something like:
x1 = 23 + 17x3
x2 = -28 - 21x3
x3 = 0?

Comment: @user3763833 not $x_3 = 0$, $x_3 = t$ or $s$ or some parameter. The parameter can take _multiple_ values and still satisfy your equations.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This answers my question!

Answer (score 0):

Let every column correspond to a $x_n$. So for the first row, the equation will be something like $$(1)x_1 + (0)x_2 + (-17)x_3 = 23$$ and the second row equation will be $$(0)x_1 + (1)x_2 + (21)x_3 = -28$$ then you just solve for $x_1$ and $x_2$ where $x_3$ is a free variable.

Answer (score 0):

$x + y + 4z = -5 \Rightarrow x = -5 - y - 4z$ (i)

$4x + 3y -5z = 8 \Rightarrow -20 -4y - 16z + 3y - 5z = 8 \Rightarrow - 21z - 28 = y(z)$

(i) $\Rightarrow x(z) = -5 +21z + 28 - 4z = 17z + 23$

$(x,y,z) = (17z + 23, - 21z - 28, z) = z (17, - 21, 1) + (23, - 28, 0)$